# Beginner JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was wondering if anyone knows the reason for [i-1] in the fourth line when you also have i++ in the second line? Thank you for any help! (It's from the book "JavaScript" by Vodnik and Gosselin.)

```
if (figureCount === 3) {

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
filename = "images/IMG_0" + photoOrder[i] + "sm.jpg";
currentFig = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i - 1];
currentFig.src = filename;
}//end of for loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some developers get confused with the for loop operators logic instead of doing it correctly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
```

they decided to add some extra processing to the mix ( which isn't that big of a deal ) but iv'e fired developers for less.

CurrentFig is using i - 1 because it appears there is a prepended img element so the developer also chose to select it as well instead of selecting the exact elements that he needs.

Comment: While I agree that starting with an `i` of `0` is more helpful in this instance, could you please add some slight explanation of why this is the case? And also why the subtraction would be needed in `currentFig`? That would really help improve the quality of your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It because [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)(similar to array) hence. So accessing the 1st(and subsequent) `img` tag on the page are done through setting `i-1`

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` return a HTMLCollection which is not an array but an array like object. So to access any element from that collection you can pass the index.

`document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i - 1]` is creating a collection of all the img tags & it is accessing specific element in that collection by passing the index `[i-1]`

In the below example `[1]` is trying to access the second element from the collection

```js
var getAllDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
console.log(getAllDiv[1].innerHTML)
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```